# How to find records from yesterdays time till todays time in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find records from yesterdays 10:30 PM till today's 10:30 PM with SQL query. Please help me with sql query to find such records.

Maybe its a duplicate question, if so please link me to that. Don't want any pl-sql function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to subtract times and compare dates.  So, one way is:

```
select t.*
from t
where trunc(datecol) = trunc(sysdate - 1.5/24);
```

It is more efficient to use a direct comparison (because Oracle can more readily use an index):

```
select t.*
from t
where datecol >= trunc(sysdate) - 1.5/24 and
      datecol < trunc(sysdate) + 1 - 1.5/24;
```

Note:  You can also use `interval` for this purpose, if you are less old-fashioned than I am:

```
select t.*
from t
where datecol >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '90' minute 
      datecol < trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' day - interval '90' minute;
```

Comment: Didn't understood it initially, but got it now.  Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the yesterday date with `SYSDATE - 1`. You would need something like this:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
WHERE date_field BETWEEN SYSDATE-1 AND SYSDATE
```